# Dynamically change the id passed to a handler in asp page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my starting point, it worked ok

```
<asp:Image ID="imageID" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Handler1.ashx?id=5BE28997-91E4-4F71-A748-9BDEF27A5FDD" />
```

I am trying to pass a variable to the handler, instead of the GUID.
In my code I have defined the property, and its value to a GUID

```
   Public Property QuID As String

    QuizID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("ID").ToString
```

I am trying to replace the passed guid with a variable 
in my page the variable bein 'QuID'

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Handler1.ashx?id=<%#=QuID %>" />
```

This is being created in my source

```
<img id="image1" src="Handler1.ashx?id=&lt;%#=QuID %>" />
```

I'm getting the variable name not the content.

I have tried a few other thing I found on google but no luck.

Can you tell me the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Why not set the the ImageUrl directly in code behind instead of a (incorrect) binding expression?

Comment: I tried that also...  I cant get it to work for me... The ~/ got dropped so the handler could not be found.

Comment: You usually do `image1.ImageUrl = "/Handler1.ashx?id=" + QuID;`